# Prestashop: Add a single product attribute on the product list / product page

Tags: attributes, prestashop, product

I'm working on a shoe store. Each shoe has some a product attributes: the brand, size, model,...
However each shoe always only has 1 brand. 
So i want to display the brand attribute beneath the product name in the product list.

I added a screenshot for more clarity. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ru3C4.jpg
You have the product name 'boots / enkellaarzen'.
Under that you have the brand name 'baci'. This name has to be dynamicly 'retrieved'.

Is this possible? If so, how do i do this?

Tldr: what is the shortcode to retrieve a product attribute in prestashop?

Comment: What PS version are you using?

Comment: Prestashop v 1.6.1.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a brand wouldn't it make more sense that the brand is manufacturer and not attribute?

You can set it in the product tab `Associations` at the bottom and display it in the template `product-list.tpl` with

```
{$product.manufacturer_name|escape:'htmlall':'utf8'}
```

Comment: Cool suggestion, i made the changes. However in the layered filter there is still an issue: it says 'fabrikant' = manufacturer, but i need it to say 'merk' = brand. I tried changing in the translation setttings, but without any effect. http://imgur.com/a/n0yA9

Comment: @Jacob Are you sure you are translating the correct string? You have to go to translations and select type translation as "Installed modules translations", select proper theme and language. Then find "blocklayered" section and translate "Manufacturer" field.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks ! There seems to be a problem when i add {$product.manufacturer_name|escape:'htmlall':'utf8'} on the product.tpl page

Comment: @Jacob On the product.tpl page it's different, you have to use `{$product->manufacturer_name|escape:'htmlall':'utf-8'}`